# How to solve "The username or password for the connection pool named |apex||, are invalid, expired, or the account is locked"?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle 19.3 CDB database.

I installed Apex 21 successfully and I'm trying to configure ORDS.

**ORDS_PUBLIC_USER** is unlocked and the password is correct :

```
alter session set container=cdb$root;
select * from dba_users where username = 'ORDS_PUBLIC_USER';
```

[image]

I also made sure Apex passwords are correct and apex users are unlocked :

```
alter session set container=pdb1;
select * from dba_users order by username;
```

[image]

However when launching ORDS using the following command, I'm getting the error :

```
java -jar ords.war standalone

The username or password for the connection pool named |apex||, are invalid, expired, or the account is locked
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not familiar with multi-tenant databases.

Here is my ORDS configuration file:

```
    <properties>
    <comment>Saved on Sat Jun 25 02:35:58 CEST 2022</comment>
    <entry key="cache.caching">false</entry>
    <entry key="cache.directory">/tmp/apex/cache</entry>
    <entry key="cache.duration">days</entry>
    <entry key="cache.expiration">7</entry>
    <entry key="cache.maxEntries">500</entry>
    <entry key="cache.monitorInterval">60</entry>
    <entry key="cache.procedureNameList"/>
    <entry key="cache.type">lru</entry>
    <entry key="database.api.enabled">true</entry>
    <entry key="db.connectionType">basic</entry>
    <entry key="db.hostname">somehost</entry>
    <entry key="db.port">1521</entry>
    <entry key="db.servicename">something.com</entry>
    <entry key="debug.debugger">false</entry>
    <entry key="debug.printDebugToScreen">false</entry>
    <entry key="error.keepErrorMessages">true</entry>
    <entry key="error.maxEntries">50</entry>
    <entry key="feature.sdw">true</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.DriverType">thin</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.InactivityTimeout">1800</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.InitialLimit">3</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MaxConnectionReuseCount">1000</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MaxLimit">10</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MaxStatementsLimit">10</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MinLimit">1</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.statementTimeout">900</entry>
    <entry key="log.logging">false</entry>
    <entry key="log.maxEntries">50</entry>
    <entry key="misc.compress"/>
    <entry key="misc.defaultPage">apex</entry>
    <entry key="restEnabledSql.active">true</entry>
    <entry key="security.disableDefaultExclusionList">false</entry>
    <entry key="security.maxEntries">2000</entry>
    <entry key="security.requestValidationFunction">wwv_flow_epg_include_modules.authorize</entry>
    <entry key="security.validationFunctionType">plsql</entry>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Is your `db.servicename` parameter something.com referring to the CDB root or PDB service? (Not sure which is correct in this situation but I'm guessing you've got the wrong one... looks like APEX should be using the PDB?)

Comment: APEX should be installed in the PDB. The CDB should never be used for application code or objects; it's purpose is to manage PDBs, and that's all.

Comment: @AlexPoole you're right ! Indeed it has to be the PDB. I changed the db.servicename to the PDB and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @AlexPoole how to find the db.servicename for PDB?

Comment: @ThejeshPR - `lsnrctl services` (on the DB server) will show you all the service names registered with the listener.